# how to implement reminder functionality using jnotify or any other way?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jnotify

I have an event model which has `is_reminder` field.  So when user
clicks dis checkbox a notification should be shown to him after every
2-3   minutes.

I heard of jnotify plug in but i could not find any
example or tutorial of using it in rails...

how can i do dis reminder
functionality using jnotify or by any other way?

Comment: What is it with the indention?

Answer (score 0):

You don't clarify about `is_remainder` field, but to show a notification after 2/3 minutes after a checkbox click can be done like following:

```
$('ID_OR_CLASS_OF_YOUR_CHECKBOX').on('change', function() {

  setTimeout(function() {

     alert('you  have a notification');

  }, 1000 * 60 * 2); // here I set the time for 2 minutes

});
```

Comment: why dis var timer = null? wat it does?